# AJAX updates div only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using AJAX first time and I have following problem

I have description and below I have field with button where I can input new description, after click on button I'd like to refresh only description using AJAX.

```
//_description.html.erb
 <div class="description-field">
        <%= @description.text %>
 </div>
```

In my controller in update I set format.js

```
//update.js.erb
$('.description-field').replaceWith("<%= @description.text %>");
```

and

```
//_description.html.erb
 <%= simple_form_for @description, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :text %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

But unfortunatelly, it refreshes description only once, when I click button second time there is no change, I had to refresh site to see new text.
Could someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.replacewith` replaces the entire html element, not just the content it contains. Change `$('.description-field').replaceWith("<%= @description.text %>");` to `$('.description-field').html("<%= escape_javascript @description.text %>");`

Also use `escape_javascript` as I did just to be safe.